# Do make distance on/get distance on mean the same thing?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

Today I've heard "*make distance on*" in the context on skateboarding. A guy on YouTube was talking about a process of him skating a long and circular rail. He spoke of how it was very hard to begin grinding this particular obstacle but when he got used to he said that he "*started to make distance on this rail*".

The second context I heard this phrase in was when 2 comedians were talking about certain phisological function and the fluid that it produces (I won't specify it on account of being afrait to be banned). They were doing a podcast while sitting at a long table and one of them was talking about the impressive distance that he can reach during this physiological "*event*". He said to the other guy "*If we were standing at the end of this table, I'm getting distance on this table*".

I feel like in the first context the meaning is that he started to grind the rail on his skateboard for longer distance and in the second that he made it to the other end of the table. I don't know why. It's just a feeling I have. What both of these phrases mean exactly?

1. a distant place or time: he lives at a distance from his work.(Collins English Dictionary)
2. a long race
   *distance training*(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: These aren't "standard English", so you won't find them in dictionaries. Feasibly one or both might be "domain-specific" usages with meanings known to the people who operate in the relevant domain. But that's nothing to do with "learning English". Just go for your best guess that makes sense in the context, same as anyone else.

Comment: my guess is the skateboarder means he can stay on course for a relatively long distance. The podcaster is probably just babbling more or less incoherently about the size of the table.

Comment: We can ask "Are you **making** progress?"  It means, "Are you progressing"?" That is, getting closer to your goal, or getting better at something. I think the locution  with "distance" is simply substituting something less abstract for the word "progress".

Comment: [Today, I heard, not have heard]

Comment: @Lambie I'm really confused that you correct me on this because the present perfect construction is used when action of the doer is finished but the time is not finished, in this case "today". In this tense "I have" is followed by past participle form of the verb. In this case "heard". Everything seems to be correct to me. Can you elaborate on what you think is incorrect here?

Comment: That's incorrect, Static Bounce. That is true (in conversation) when the time period is not over, for example, But here, that is not clear at all since we have no idea what "today" means. We all live in different time zones and you heard it once, right? So, it is more reasonable to use the simple past. The speakers are usually in the same place at the same time. The timeframe has to be really clear: A mother would say to a kid: **Have you seen** your father this today? [The day is not over]. Yes, Mum, I **saw him five minutes ago**.

Comment: @Lambie So if I do it online and there is a timestamp with the date and time it still doesn't justify using this form?

Comment: That is not relevant.  You finished skateboarding and that is when **you heard it**.

Comment: But the day that I wrote the post is the day that I heard it? Wouldn't that justify the use of present perfect? This is what the tense is used for. Action finished + time not finished.

Answer (score 0):

These both seem like edge cases so I wouldn't worry much about them. The skateboard usage may be unique to skateboarding. The comedians' usage is still unusual, but not unheard of, and other similar constructions are a bit more common. I feel like this often happens in sports contexts, in which competitors might "get some [abstract type of measurement, often with intensifiers or modifiers]," like "He got some impressive height on that triple salchow," or "she got some real speed on that straightaway." In this usage, these abstracts like "distance" or "height" are used as if they're noncount nouns of quantity—rather than "a distance," they speak of "some distance" or "a lot of distance" or "more distance than the other guy," so you can understand "she got some distance on that throw" as "she achieved a notable 'amount of distance' with that throw."

As long as you understand such usages, I wouldn't worry about adopting them; they're only appropriate in casual conversational usage, and you can always use other constructions like "That throw went a long way!"

Comment: But "He got some impressive height on that triple salchow" is not the same as "He got hight on that tripple salchow". Do you mean to say that in "I'm getting distance on this table" it's implied that the distance is of considerable lenght? Or perhaps it's even implied that it's the entire lenght of the table?